# The following packages have unmet dependencies and could not initialize package information

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I know that this might seem to be duplicate of other questions. But none of the answers mentioned there solved this:

- When I try to update my system using Software Updates, I get an error message saying :

  [image]
- When I try `sudo apt-get upgrade` , I get this:

  ```
  vishwa@vishwa-PC:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   libcogl15 : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0) but it is not installed
   libqt5gui5 : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0) but it is not installed
  E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
  ```
- When I run `sudo apt-get -f install` :

  ```
  vishwa@vishwa-PC:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  Correcting dependencies... failed.
  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
   libcogl15 : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0) but it is not installed
   libqt5gui5 : Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0) but it is not installed
  E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
  E: Unable to correct dependencies
  ```
- My Software-Properties-gtk looks like this :

  [image]

All answers are welcome. Please help me here.

EDIT :
@Raphael ,
 - Out put of `mkdir ~/Downloads/tmp; cd ~/Downloads/tmp; wget -c http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgbm1_10.1.0-4ubuntu5_amd‌​64.deb; sudo dpkg -i *.deb; rm -rf ~/Downloads/tmp` :

```
  --2016-01-20 22:06:42--  http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgbm1_10.1.0-4ubuntu5_amd%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B64.deb
Resolving kr.archive.ubuntu.com (kr.archive.ubuntu.com)... 103.22.220.133
Connecting to kr.archive.ubuntu.com (kr.archive.ubuntu.com)|103.22.220.133|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-01-20 22:06:43 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2016-01-20 22:06:43--  http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgbm1_10.1.0-4ubuntu5_amd%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B64.deb
Reusing existing connection to kr.archive.ubuntu.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-01-20 22:06:43 ERROR 404: Not Found.

dpkg: error processing archive *.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 *.deb
vishwa@vishwa-PC:~/Downloads/tmp$
```

NOTE : I Use Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

- Output of `apt-cache policy libgbm1` :

  `vishwa@vishwa-PC:~$ apt-cache policy libgbm1
  libgbm1:
    Installed: 10.1.0-4ubuntu5
    Candidate: 11.0.4~git20151026+11.0.ec14e6f8-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty
    Version table:
       11.0.4~git20151026+11.0.ec14e6f8-0ubuntu0ricotz~trusty 0
          500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
       10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5 0
          500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
   *** 10.1.0-4ubuntu5 0
          500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
          100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
  vishwa@vishwa-PC:~$`

Comment: Did you try installing the packages externally?

Comment: @Raphael could you please elaborate?

Comment: Do this `mkdir ~/Downloads/tmp; cd ~/Downloads/tmp; wget -c http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgbm1_10.1.0-4ubuntu5_amd64.deb; sudo dpkg -i *.deb; rm -rf ~/Downloads/tmp`

Comment: Copy the whole and paste it then run it.

Comment: Comment if it worked.

Comment: @Raphael I tried what you said , but....  (Question updated)

Comment: The above link seems to be down for some reason, do this instead: `mkdir ~/Downloads/tmp; cd ~/Downloads/tmp; wget -c http://th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libgbm1_10.1.0-4ubuntu5_amd64.deb; sudo dpkg -i *.deb; rm -rf ~/Downloads/tmp`

Comment: @Raphael  sadly I think  even this link is down too. I have sent you the Output of this command in General room  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Also, what's the output of `apt-cache policy libgbm1`?

Comment: Then do this: `mkdir ~/Downloads/tmp; cd ~/Downloads/tmp` Now goto [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libgbm1/download) and download the file from the available server, then, copy it to `~/Downloads/tmp` and finally run the command `sudo dpkg -i *.deb; rm -rf ~/Downloads/tmp` in the previously open terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as we have found out in our chat room that the error was being caused by a `ppa` - `ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa` and all its packages. Removing it and adding a new `ppa` for nvidia drivers `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` solved the issue. Glad! we worked it out.